# Gitlab-runner dind results in ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380:

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

The executor for the project gitlab-runner is docker. I try to run docker-in-docker and I get the following Error from pipeline:

> ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: process_linux.go:508: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused: resulting devices cgroup doesn't match target mode: unknown (docker.go:385:0s)

I followed this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-continuous-deployment-pipeline-with-gitlab-ci-cd-on-ubuntu-18-04 and after I read the docs of gitlab CI/CD and gitlab-runner, but I can't find out how to solve this problem.

This is currently my config.toml file:

```
check_interval = 0
log_level = "debug"

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "docker-runner"
  url = my-url
  token = token
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:20"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

and this is my gitlab-ci.yaml

```
stages:
  - publish

variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

publish:
  image: docker:20
  stage: publish
  tags:
    - publish
  services:
    - docker:20-dind
  script:
    - docker version
```

First I don't understand the Error message and second how this can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a downgrade of docker:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall docker-ce=5:18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic docker-ce-cli=5:18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic docker-ce-rootless-extras containerd.io=1.3.9-1`

The problem was that I run on a V-Server (Virtuozzo) with Ubuntu 18. It seems that Virtuozzo does not support currently the newest Docker Engine.